# How to click on the last element from dropdown with DIV class using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuIppLogs" data-bind="foreach: (ippLogs == null ? [] : ippLogs.files)">
                                                        <div class="dropdown-divider dropdown-divider-file" data-bind="visible: $index() > 0" style="display: none;"></div>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-file" data-bind="attr: {id: 'logs_file_' + $index()}, html: filename, click: $root.downloadIppLog" id="logs_file_0">bugreport-00908fc8b487-c470hd-1.18.359-2022-07-26-20-46-18.tar.gz</div>
                                                      
                                                        <div class="dropdown-divider dropdown-divider-file" data-bind="visible: $index() > 0"></div>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-file" data-bind="attr: {id: 'logs_file_' + $index()}, html: filename, click: $root.downloadIppLog" id="logs_file_1">bugreport-00908fc8b487-c470hd-1.18.359-2022-07-26-20-50-19.tar.gz</div>
                                                      
                                                        <div class="dropdown-divider dropdown-divider-file" data-bind="visible: $index() > 0"></div>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-file" data-bind="attr: {id: 'logs_file_' + $index()}, html: filename, click: $root.downloadIppLog" id="logs_file_2">bugreport-00908fc8b487-c470hd-1.18.359-2022-07-26-20-52-20.tar.gz</div>
                                                      </div>
```

I need to click on the last element from drop down:
[image]

the dropdown in div class:
I want to click on the last element- now its ID is 'logs_file_2' , but we may have more elements with groing index
[image]

I tried next:

```
config_id=0
             while self.selenium.webdriver.find_elements(by=By.ID, value=f'logs_file_{config_id}'):

                     a = self.selenium.webdriver.get_element_object(by=By.ID, value=f'logs_file_{config_id}')

                     config_id=config_id+1

            a.action(Actions.CLICK)
```

But wasn't managed to.
Please, suggest.

Comment: Can you share the url of the page please

Comment: This is local device manager in my work, unfortunately i cant share url

Answer (score 0):

The following code should isolate the last element within that class, and click on it (chromedriver/selenium setup is for debian/linux, your may be different, so just do the correct imports, and adapt it as needed):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

actions = ActionChains(browser)

url='your_internal_url'
browser.get(url)

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-left'))).click()

items_to_click_on = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dropdown-item.dropdown-item-file")))
items_to_click_on[-1].click()
```